# how to make a calendarView visible but not editable with pre chosen date

Tags: android, widget, calendarview

I want to make a Calendar View visible but doesn't editable, only shown to the user with a selected date I tried to set a clickable attribute to false, but it didn't work. and I added a container view then set the clickable attribute to false, but didn't work also

```
    <CalendarView
            android:clickable="false"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: the post edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a workaround, I wrapped it with another view then control the click listener for that view this the only solution that worked for me, and here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:id="@+id/FL"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView android:id="@+id/calendarView"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <View android:id="@+id/empty"
              android:layout_width="409dp"
              android:layout_height="336dp"
              android:background="@android:color/transparent"
              android:elevation="16dp"
              app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/calendarView"
              app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/calendarView"
              app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
              app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/calendarView"
              app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/calendarView"
              app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To Control the listeners :

```
private fun enableCalendar() {
    empty.setOnClickListener(null)
    empty.visibility = View.GONE
}

private fun disableCalendar() {
    empty.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    empty.setOnClickListener {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By returning `true` from dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) will solve your problem.

Use this class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.CalendarView;

public class CalenderView extends CalendarView {


    public CalenderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CalenderView(Context context, AttributeSet attribute) {
        super(context, attribute);
    }

    public CalenderView(Context context, AttributeSet attribute, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attribute, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

For Kotlin it will be:

```
 import android.content.Context
 import android.util.AttributeSet
 import android.view.MotionEvent
 import android.widget.CalendarView

 class CalendarView : CalendarView {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, attribute: AttributeSet?) : super(context!!, attribute) 
    {}
    constructor(context: Context?, attribute: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : 
    super(context!!, attribute, defStyle) {}

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return true
    }
  }
```